# How can I reduce 120 VAC 60 Hz gradually to zero in a 8 seconds?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, control

Need help on a project where after a pressing a button 120 VAC voltage drops gradually to 0V in 8 seconds. Second button will restore full voltage again. Load is a big magnet and its current can be as high as 20 A! Since each cycle (60 Hz) is about 16 ms, I wounder if counting about 600 zero crossing (opto MOC3020 and IC 4040 perhaps) could provide some kind off control serially putted between de outlet and the load. Since is imperative keeping the sinusoidal shape thyristors can not be used!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're not doing your design for you.

Comment: I'd just turn up and down variac down slowly.

Comment: Hmm perhaps a PWM type VFD with an output filter would do the trick.  Not PFM type due to the filter.  Electromagnets are inductive, so the magnet can provide some of the filtering and if operational frequency is high enough you may not need an output filter on the VFD.  Why do you *think* you need a pure sine wave?

Comment: I guess it's also worth asking why you're using AC with a large electromagnet as well?  Degausser?  2400W is a fairly huge load to just mess around with, so building your own VFD without a degree is probably not an option.  Most 120V circuits are limited to 1500W as well, so I hope you've thought about what you want to plug this thing into.  This question may fall into the category of a way too big "do my project for me", but it could be reasonable to tell you ways this can be accomplished, leaving the actual work to yourself.

Comment: As you might already know, you can't decrease the voltage on the outlet directly. And since it's mandatory to keep the voltage waveform (i.e. not to use switching components), you should make your own inverter and control the output voltage through it.

Comment: This is my first question directed to Stack .I am not acquainted with the right procedures to interact with these answers  "Hearth" said  " I’m voting to close this question because we're not doing your design for you" honestly I do not understand what this means .

Comment: DKNguyen using a variac does not complies because the process must be done automatically from a button

Comment: KH - operational frequency is 60Hz  Sinusoidal shape has been proved empirically to be the best choice to avoid spikes back from the  inductive load .

Comment: KH - Special degausser for pretty small pieces whose metallography retains Magnetic remnant even after submitted to traditional methods is the goal . Yes ! EGS002 driving a full IGBT  bridge could eventually do this job through RS232 commands according to its datasheet . Unhappily ,even after three phone calls and several emails the manufacture(China) y did not respond .That is why I began to search for others alternatives !

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a manual method, a variac can provide a smooth taper-off of AC voltage (I'm assuming you want to use this to make a demagnetizer.) This would be safer than making some kind of drive circuit, at least in the near term.

There are motor-driven variacs as well, though the ones I spotted were on the expensive side. You could probably adapt one using a DC gearmotor and limit sensors.

Comment: +1 for motor driven variac.

Comment: hacktastical - Yes a variac would do the job but the process must happens automatically  after just pressing a button or initiated from a pulse . Motor drive variac has costs issues . Anyway I am very grateful for the attention I got from every one in this case . Thanks for  the attention patience and kindness to give their opinion .